# Resize UITableView to iPhone 5/5s

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

How can I adapt my UITableView height based on iPhone screen size (i.e. adapt to iP5)? On iPhone 4/4s, the UITableView adapts until the bottom of the UIView but on iPhone 5 doesn't. I've autolayout enabled and i already tried to run the next code (unsuccessful):

```
self.friendsTable.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight ;
```

Any idea?

On iPhone 4/4s:

[image: iPhone 4/4s]

On iPhone 5/5s:

[image: iPhone 5/5s]

XIB:
[image]

Comment: better to go with two different xibs

Comment: If you use autolayout you should set appropriate constraints, autoresizing mask is not used in autolayout

Comment: @Vladimir I'm new in iOS development and i don't know yet how to define appropriate constraints. How can i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In IB, select your table view. Select "Editor" in the top menu. Select Pin. Then select "Bottom Space to Superview". Make sure Autolayout is enabled. That should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

So if you are using autolayout you just have to set the "Bottom Space to Superview", you can do it selecting your UITableView then select Editor > Pin (top menu).
Or select the UITableview and set the autolayout through the shortcuts, like showing in image below.

[image]

If you are not using autolayout select your UITableView select the view "Show the Size inspector" and adjust the size like the image below.

[image]

I hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.friendsTable.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight ;
self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Autolayout just add constraint "Bottom space to Superview". I hope it should solve your issue.
Thanks